# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried every possible method to resolve this issue.
I am using `firebase firestore` for database.

This is how my data looks in the `Firestore` -  [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtEjX.png)
This is how my `files directory` looks-  [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO1z8.png)

So,I am fetching the data from `Firestore` and passing that data to `CardUIVerify.js` and `CardUIBan.js`.

```
Order of data- Data.js->CardUIVerify.js,CardUIBan.js->Panel.js->App.js->index.js
```

Code for fetching data from `firestore`(filename-`Data.js`)-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import fire from "../Firebase";

export const DataContext = createContext();

export function DataProvider({ children }) {
  const [showdata, setShowData] = useState([]);

  const fetchedItem = async () => {
    var usersRef = await fire.firestore().collection(`users`);
    var response = await usersRef
      .where("isVerified", "==", false)
      .where("certificate", "==", null);

    response.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      var data = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        data.push(...showdata, doc.data());
      });
      setShowData(data);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchedItem();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <DataContext.Provider value={[showdata, setShowData, fetchedItem]}>
        {children}
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is the code for `CardUIVerify.js`-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./CardUIVerify.css";
import { DataContext } from "../contexts/Data";

function UIVerify() {
  const [showdata, setShowData] = useContext(DataContext);

  function renderCard(card) {
    return (
      <div id="grid1">
        <Card id="card-shape1" key={card.uid}>
          <Card.Img className="card-img1" variant="top" src={card.photoUrl} />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title id="title1">
              {card.name},{card.gender == "Male" ? <></> : <>‍♀️</>}
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text className="details1">{card.about}</Card.Text>
            <Button
              className="custom-button11"
              variant="primary"
              size="md"
              active
              block
            >
              View Certificate
            </Button>
            <Button className="custom-button21" variant="success" active block>
              Verify
            </Button>
            <Button className="custom-button31" variant="danger" active block>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div>{showdata && showdata.map(renderCard)}</div>;
}
export default UIVerify;
```

This is the code for `CardUIBan.js`-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Card, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./CardUIBan.css";
import { DataContext } from "../contexts/Data";

function UIBan() {
  const [showdata, setShowData] = useContext(DataContext);

  function renderCard(card) {
    return (
      <div id="grid2">
        <Card id="card-shape2" key={card.uid}>
          <Card.Img className="card-img2" variant="top" src={card.photoUrl} />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title id="title2">
              {card.name},{card.gender == "Male" ? <></> : <>‍♀️</>}
            </Card.Title>
            <Card.Text className="details2">{card.about}</Card.Text>
            <Button
              className="custom-button12"
              variant="primary"
              size="md"
              active
              block
            >
              View Obligations
            </Button>
            <Button className="custom-button22" variant="danger" active block>
              Ban User
            </Button>
            <Button className="custom-button32" variant="success" active block>
              Unban User
            </Button>
            <Button className="custom-button42" variant="danger" active block>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <div>{showdata && showdata.map(renderCard)}</div>;
}
export default UIBan;
```

This is the code for `Panel.js`-

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import fire from "../Firebase";
import "./Panel.css";
import UIVerify from "./CardUIVerify";
import { DataContext } from "../contexts/Data";
import UIBan from "./CardUIBan";

function Panel() {

  const [showdata, setShowData, fetchedItem] = useContext(DataContext);
    
  function search1(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      fetchedItem();
    }
  }

  function search2(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      fetchedItem();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="app-panel">
      <div className="header-div">
        <h1 id="header">Welcome Admin</h1>
        <button className="panel-button" onClick={() => fire.auth().signOut()}>
          Sign out
        </button>
      </div>

      <div className="verification-div">
        <h2 className="v-header">Verification</h2>
        <input
          className="search-1"
          name="search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search.."
          autocomplete="off"
          onKeyPress={search1}
        />
        <UIVerify />
      </div>

      <div className="banned-div">
        <h2 className="b-header">Suspend</h2>
        <input
          className="search-2"
          name="search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search.."
          autocomplete="off"
          onKeyPress={search2}
        />
        <UIBan />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Panel;
```

This is the code for `App.js`-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Panel from "./components/Panel";
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute";
import { AuthProvider } from "./Auth";
import { DataProvider } from "./contexts/Data";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Router>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Panel} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the code for `index.js`-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { DataProvider } from "./contexts/Data";
import { AuthProvider } from "./Auth";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <DataProvider>
        <App />
      </DataProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This is how my error looks-
[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ut5N.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you render an array of components React will complain about needing the key attribute.

In your case its probably the line `return <div>{showdata && showdata.map(renderCard)}</div>;` causing you issues. To fix it just do something like changing `<div id="grid2">` to `<div id="grid2" key={card.id}>`  if you don't have an id attribute use whatever uniquely identifies the card.

Comment: Worked like a gem. Thank u so much!!